# Border overlaps form when window is resized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form surrounded by a border. When the window is resized the border sometimes overlaps the form. This should not happen.

See the fiddle output:

http://jsfiddle.net/sdSdW/embedded/result/

Can someone tell me what I have to change in my source to make the border surrounding my form, keeping a distance between the form and the border even if the window is resized.
I do not want to make the border fixed width (if not really necessary)

See the fiddle source:

http://jsfiddle.net/sdSdW/

Comment: This is default behavior, there are two ways to solve it. Give the parent a fixed width or give the form a dynamic width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need many parents for the border. You can add the border to `fieldset` itself

try -

```
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sdSdW/2/)

Comment: Perfect. That does the trick! Thanks.. http://jsfiddle.net/sdSdW/1/embedded/result/